# Cannot correctly get form data in google script

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to submit form data to google sheet via ajax but google script if else statement not work.

Below is the google script

```
// original from: http://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/
// original gist: https://gist.github.com/willpatera/ee41ae374d3c9839c2d6 

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Records";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){

      switch (headers[i]) {
        case "Timestamp":
          row.push(new Date());
          break;
        case "LogTime":
          row.push(new Date());
          break;
        default:
          row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
          break;
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

I submit the form data using ajax

HTML

```
<form id="checkin-form">
<input type="hidden" name="Event"  value="<?php echo $events[1]; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LogTime" value="" />
...
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('#checkin-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#checkin-form").serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
```

From google script, the column LogTime cannot get the Date() but keep empty. What is the possible issue?

Here is the google sheet column
[image]

Best regards,

Kelvin

Comment: Why not `console.log(header);` and see what it is?  Maybe its not what you think it is.

Comment: And maybe `e` also

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes, you are right but I can't see any log, how can I enable it and troubleshoot it?

Comment: Check "Executions" on the left side of the script editor.

Comment: @Kelvin Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification, no error occurs. I deeply apologize that my test works fine. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. From your reply, I understood that your issue has been resolved. I'm glad for it. In this case, my answer was not useful for your situation. So I have to delete it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the google apps script does not work, finally, I found the article from https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175, when I redo running the Setup function, everything works properly. The Setup function has already been run before and the script worked.